# configuration of .htaccess for add_rewrite_rule to make sense

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am trying this code from [codex wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

How must by .htaccess file must be configured for above code to make sense? If I put the basic wordpress `.htaccess` configuration file then I get redirected to same page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

after adding a new rule, you have to flush the rewrite-rules in order to use them

that can be done with the "flush_rewrite_rules" function
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

or it can be done in going in the Administration Screens -> Settings -> Permalink and just saving without changing something on this screen